# Hide text after br tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wondering is there anyway to hide text after a br tag . I've a content like this

```
<div class="lyric">
 Track List: 
 <br>1/a
 <br>2/b
 <br>3/c
 <br>4/d
 <br>5/e 
 <br>6/f   
 <br>
</div>
```

I only want display 3 track  ,hide another track , when people click button show more  it will show all the track . EX:

```
<div class="lyric">
 Track List: 
 <br>1/a
 <br>2/b
 <br>3/c
</div>
```

Before my content look like this :

```
<div class="lyric">
 Track List: 
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
</div>
```

So my code look like this :

```
if ( $('.lyric div').length > 5 ) {        
        $('.lyric div:gt(5)').hide();
        $('.show-more').removeClass('hidden');
    }
```

Now my content changed look like first exmaple , so i don't know how to hide it

Comment: Why not use a `<ul><li></li></ul>` to show the tracks? Its more semantically correct

Comment: To use `<br />` is not the best way here. It's not an element that carries any content.

Comment: I get the content from another website . and it look like my exxample

Comment: +1: there is nothing wrong with this question. Sometimes you get stuck with a fixed structure defined by somebody else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can't without restructuring the DOM a little as you can't style out the remaining text blocks without a parent element.

jQuery makes it easy to change the DOM however :)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pc1k9Lt0/4/

```
// Wrap all text elements in divs
$('.lyric').each(function () {
    var $lyric = $(this);
    var contents = $(this).contents();
    contents.each(function () {
        $lyric.append($('<div>').html(this));
    });
        // Remove all the br elements
    $('br', $lyric).parent().remove();
});

// Hide what you do not want visible
$('.lyric div:gt(2)').hide();

// Toggle visibility on click
$('#show').click(function () {
    $('.lyric div:gt(2)').toggle();
});
```

You can do the same thing with `UL` and `LI` if you want (just insert a `UL` as the parent and use `LI` instead of `DIV` in my example)

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pc1k9Lt0/8/

Note: *I needed to ignore any blank text block - i.e. the last item :)*

```
// Wrap all text elements in LIs
$('.lyric').each(function () {
    var $lyric = $(this);
    var contents = $(this).contents();
    contents.each(function () {
        var $li = $('<li>').html(this);
        if ($.trim($li.text()) != ""){
            $lyric.append($li);
        }
    });
        // Remove all the br elements
    $('br', $lyric).parent().remove();
    $lyric.children().wrapAll('<ul>');
});

// Hide what you do not want visible
$('.lyric li:gt(2)').hide();

// Toggle visibility on click
$('#show').click(function () {
    $('.lyric li:gt(2)').toggle();
});
```

Comment: i'm also thinking of changing div with br . Your code help me a lot . Thank You :)